# Writing a Cron Job That Can Access User Data

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to write a cron job that runs a report, and emails the result to an address defined in my user's ~/.bashrc file. I had this working perfectly on Fedora, but when I switched to Ubuntu, my solution no longer works. The command my cron job currently runs is:

```
. /home/myuser/.bashrc; /home/myuser/bin/runreport
```

If I run that command manually, or start it via Gnome-Schedule, it works perfectly, but it never seems to run. Is there something specific to Ubuntu that would be blocking this from running?

Output of crontab -l:

```
0 8 * * * . /home/myuser/.bashrc; /home/myuser/bin/runreport # JOB_ID_1
```

Output of grep -i cron /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug  4 08:00:00 localhost CRON[23234]: (myuser) CMD (. /home/myuser/.bashrc; /home/myuser/bin/runreport # JOB_ID_1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the command you're running?   In the description you say you define things in .bashrc but then in the command you load .bash_rc

Comment: does your bash_rc export its vars? What does grep -i cron /var/log/syslog show?

Comment: Can you post the crontab entry for this command.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant .bashrc, not .bash_rc, although the result is the same with either. I've corrected my post. Also added outputs of the other commands.

Comment: @Doom, yes, my .bashrc includes .bash_aliases which contains the line "export SMTPUSER=user@domain.com".

Comment: It seems the way Cron loads source files doesn't support the ". ~/.bash_aliases" line in .bashrc. However, even when I modify my cron command to use .bash_aliases directly, it seems able to access the exported variables, but now when it tries to read other files in my home directory, it gets a "Broken pipe" error. Is it a permissions issue? I tried adding my user to the crontab group via "sudo usermod -a -G crontab myuser" but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: For reference, have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Further%20Considerations too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/home/myuser/bin/runreport` is a script, add the following two lines to the top:

```
env
set -x
```

and change the `crontab` line to:

```
. /home/myuser/.bashrc ; /home/myuser/bin/runreport >/tmp/qq 2>&1
```

Then, when it runs, you should have all the environment variables, and the commands that were run, in the `/tmp/qq` file.

If it *isn't* a script, make a script that calls it and add the `env` line to it. That will at least give you the environment you're running in.

Comment: "runreport" is actually a Python script, with "#!/usr/bin/python" at the top. Are there equivalent lines for Python?

Comment: I had already fixed the environment problem by sourcing .bash_aliases instead of .bashrc. However, it looks like adding the "2>&1" fixed my "broken pipe" error. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris, you could probably get the environment with `os.system("env")` or just by inserting `env >tmp/qq.env` into your cron command immediately before running `runreport`. The per-line debugging is harder - it's probably easier just to add debug `print` statements to the script. Glad I could help with the pipe issues though. Cheers.